# How can I rename multiple folders and sub-files with a batch script?

Tags: batch-file, window, rename

I am making a cleanup tool that will delete and rename some specified directories and files. I can *individually* rename and delete directories and files, but I cannot rename more than one folder, and I cannot rename files within sub-directories. Here is my script:

```
if not exist Plugin mkdir Plugin
RENAME "xml" "XML"

RENAME "x64\bin.exe" "x64\bin_x64.exe"
RENAME "x64" "64bit"

RENAME "x86\bin.exe" "x86\bin_x86.exe"
RENAME "x86" "32bit"

rmdir Licenses /s /q
del bin_old.exe
del bin.exe.bak
del README.md
del license.txt
del components.xml
del InstallationLog.txt
del maintenancetool.dat
del maintenancetool.exe
del maintenancetool.ini
del maintenancetool.zip
del network.xml
```

As you can see, I want to rename the 32bit executable within the x86 directory to `bin_x86.exe`, then to rename it's containing folder from `x86` to `32bit`, and then the same equivalent for the 64bit binary and directory. Currently my script can successfully rename the first defined folder *(but not it's binary)*, and not the second folder or binary.

Comment: You have some typos there - "RANAME"

Comment: Oops, thanks for spotting that. My script doesn't actually contain the typo, so it isn't affecting the results...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RENAME command cannot work within subdirectories, so the easy solution would be to `cd` into the directories within the batch script before renaming the files.

```
cd x64
RENAME "bin.exe" "bin_x64.exe"
cd ..
RENAME "x64" "64bit"
cd x86
RENAME "bin.exe" "bin_x86.exe"
cd ..
RENAME "x86" "32bit"
```

Comment: More info here: https://ss64.com/nt/ren.html